# Finding the convergent interval of $z^{{2z}^{{3z}\ldots^{{nz}\ldots}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, tetration

I was trying to find an exact solution to $x=a^x$, and naturally derived a solution defined by infinite tetrations of $a$. I first defined a recursion equivalent to the definition of tetrations and then used invariant points to show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (^nx)$$
converges for $x \in [e^{-e}, e^{\frac{1}{e}}]$. Now, I am curious if I could extend the definition of tetrations and find the convergence interval of the following function.
$$f(x)=x^{{2x}^{{3x}^{{...}}}}$$
I find this to be hard because I cannot, as in the case of normal tetrations, define a recursion that can be applied to define $f(x)$. Any tips on how to proceed will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify, we want to define $\epsilon_1(a_1)=a_1$ and $\epsilon_{n+1}(a_1,\ldots, a_{n+1})=a_1^{\epsilon_n(a_2,\ldots, a_{n+1})}$, and then determine for which $x$ $\lim_n \epsilon_n(x,2x,\ldots,nx)$ exists?

Comment: @user114263 Yes, that is exactly what we want.

Comment: Currently thinking about the problem, and I'm not sure how useful this is, but it's clear that the set of inverses of the natural numbers can be applied.
If $x = \frac{1}{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then the $k$-th iteration yields some number which will be identical to all following iterations, thus giving a well defined number. 
Not sure yet how this extends to other numbers though.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the recursive Mathematica code ($f_{n}\left( x \right) = x^{2 \cdot x^{3 \cdot x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{ n \cdot x}}}}}}$):
```f[n_, x_, k_] := x^((k - n) * f[n - 1, x, k]); f[1, x_, k_] := x; a := 10; f[a, x, a + 2]```
where $a = n$.

Comment: Does $$x^{\displaystyle2z^{3z\cdots}}$$ mean $$x^{\displaystyle2(z^{3z\cdots})}\quad\text{or}\quad x^{\displaystyle(2z)^{3z\cdots}}\quad\text{?}$$

Comment: @GEdgar -- The operator precedence of the power function is defined as "right associative". Alas... check the system you use, even the CAS I use [does it wrong](https://sourceforge.net/p/reduce-algebra/discussion/899364/thread/a6dc89ed7b/#6d24) (and will continue to do it wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I'll be using the notation you introduced $f(x) = x^{2x^{3x\dots}}$ to refer to this function.

Like I stated in my comment, I feel like trying to make $1$s appear in the exponents somewhere is a fairly straightforward way of obtaining valid solutions, and this is rather trivial for $x = 1$ or $x = \frac{1}{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

More generally though :

- Consider the case $0< x < 1$. There exists some natural integer $k$ for which $kx < 1$, but $(k+1)x > 1$ **(read edit)**, so we can infer the limit value :
  $$kx^{(k+1)x^{(k+2)x\dots}} = 0$$
  If $k = 1$ (i.e $x < 0.5$), then $f(x) = 0$.
  But if $k > 1$ (i.e $x > 0.5$), then this would then imply $(k-1)x^{kx^{(k+1)x^{(k+2)x\dots}}} = 1$ and therefore $f(x) = 1$.
- For $x > 1$, it's quite clear that $f(x)$ cannot exist, and I don't think you're particularly interested in $x \leq 0$ so I won't touch on that in my answer.
- Edit : I just noticed by plotting an approximate of $f$ that there's something I forgot to adress in the case where $x = 0.5$. I believe $f(0.5)$ approches $0.5$ in this case due to the nature of my argument.

Funny, it seems like a convoluted way of defining $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } 0 < x < 0.5 \\ 0.5 &\text{ if } x = 0.5 \\ 1 &\text{ if } 0.5 < x \leq 1 \end{cases}$.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume $0 =< x < 1$ because otherwise things get divergent or complex.

Eventually for some $n$ we have $n x = a > 1$ and $(n-1) x = b < 1$.

Lets use $**$ for going up the power staircase.

So we get

$$x**{2x} **... ** nx **((n+1)x **...)$$

That finally reduces to

$$x**{2x} **... ** a ** ((n+1)x **...\infty)$$

and further towards

$$x**{2x} **... **b^\infty$$

Now clearly $b^\infty = 0$ and $((n-2)x)^0 = 1$.

So we get a finite power tower :

$$x**{2x} **.. **(n-3)x$$

Now if $x > 1$ we get a number larger than

$$1^{2^{3...}}$$

and if $x = 1$ we get

$$1^{2^{3...}}$$

So the sequence diverges to +infinity for $x>1$ or $x = 1$

Notice that $x<0$ gives us complex numbers.

Also $0^{0^{0^...}} = 1$ or $0$.

In conclusion, as a real function of a real variable, the only real interval that makes sense is $0= < x < 1$.

And in that case we get $f(0) = 1$ or $0$ or

$$f(x) = x**{2x} **.. **(n-3)x$$

Comment: Do you accept my answer ? 
Do you have further questions ?